# Cant create relationships / finish lookup

Tags: ssis

I need to create Lookup between Flat File Source (.csv file) and DB.

I noticed that from flat file all data is string, so I converted it in Flat File Source properties, then I sort data by t_cz_id and finnaly I'm trying to make Lookup. And now problem begins. No metter what I try, i cant create relationship between Input Columns and Lookup Columns.

I tried everything I know, first I was thinking about columns name so I created Data Convertions with same names and similar data type. Dont know what might be the case

[image]

Comment: When you attempt to drag column from left (Available input columns) to right (Available lookup columns), I assume an error message pops up indicating the data types are in conflict

Comment: @billinkc First of all I didnt know that You can drag items :D.

Cannot map the input column, 'cz_id', to the lookup column, 'fCz_id', because the data types do not match.

fCz_id data is integer, while cz_id is single-byte signed integer[DT_I1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that is reported when you attempt to map a column from the left (Available input columns) to the right (Available lookup columns) is self-explanatory if a bit maddening.

> Cannot map the input column, 'cz_id', to the lookup column, 'fCz_id', because the data types do not match. fCz_id data is integer, while cz_id is single-byte signed integer[DT_I1]

cz_id from your data flow is DT_I1 and fCz_id is a "regular" integer DT_I4. The types must match exactly to be able to define the relationship between columns.

Go back to your Flat File Source Connection manager and change the type accordingly.

Drag the columns to each other to define the relationship. Check the columns on the right if you want them added to the data flow (sometimes you only want to verify a record does/doesn't exist in the target system)